# How to make two pods, located on different Kubernetes nodes, communicate

Tags: kubernetes

I'm looking for some advice.

I've created my Kubernetes cluster, with multiple worker nodes and the control plane. I've also executed multiple pods with docker images.

What I'm looking for now is to make two pods, located on different nodes, communicate with each other. What is the easiest way to make it happen? I can figure out the details once I know how to do that, but I've tried to set up a pod running up as a service and then accessing its IP:port from the browser, to no avail. I've tried using the cluster IP, the Node IP, but that just doesn't work.

So say I want to send data x from the docker image running in Pod A, located in Node A, to Pod B in Node B. Then I want the program located in Pod B to process that data. How would you proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a very broad question, and one that it's probably already answered on SO. Nonetheless, I would suggest you read the Kubernetes [`Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) docs as well as those regardina [DNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/). You can come back to SO with a more specific question when you are done.

Comment: I knew it was a broad question, but I didn't want to dwell deep into things, just some advice on what I could do/what to look for. So I appreciate your links, will definitely check them out.

Answer (score 3):

> So say I want to send data x from the docker image running in Pod A, located in Node A, to Pod B in Node B. Then I want the program located in Pod B to process that data. How would you proceed?

Don't access the Pod directly. Deploy your application as a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) and also create a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for the application. The other application should send the request to the *Service* for the application it want to access.

When you update your application, with e.g. changed code - new Pods will be created for that application, but the *Service* is the same.

If both application is deployed in the same namespace, you typically can access the other application with e.g. `http://<service-name>`

Comment: This is incredibly useful. I already tried with Deployments and Services, but i will try accessing with the service name. Also one last thing: when you mention "sending a request to the service", does the protocol matter?

Comment: Yes, use the protocol that your app has implemented. But access the app with its service-name as domain name.